When distributing Compose Multiplatform dmg, it seems to miss javax.script
My desktop app use the ScriptEngine to do something, which I know ScriptEngine is removed after JDK 11.
So I added a dependency like this:
implementation("org.openjdk.nashorn:nashorn-core:15.3")

and some example code like this:
val manager = ScriptEngineManager()
val engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript")
val hookJsCode = """
    function test(){
        return 10;
    }
"""
engine.eval(hookJsCode)
val result = engine.eval("test()")
println(result.toString())

It's ok when I run the jar but fails when I run the dmg which I distribute.
The tip message is in the following picture
the error tip picture
I don't know what happens. Is there someone that can help me? Thanks.
PS: By the way, I use the openjdk 18 of zulu to distribute dmg. And I distribute to msi to window system it's also ok.

the compose version is 1.5.11  kotlin version is 1.9.21

I also encountered error when executing runRelease task.
I resolved the problem by creating a rules.pro file beside my build.gradle(.kts) file with the following content:
-keep class org.openjdk.nashorn.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.openjdk.nashorn.**

# If with above you still get error, try to uncomment the below line as well:
# -dontoptimize

Then in my build.gradle(.kts) file I specified that file as Proguard config:
compose.desktop {
    application {
        // ...
        nativeDistributions {
            // ...
            buildTypes.release.proguard {
                // ...
                configurationFiles.from("rules.pro")


thanks for you reply. but I only execute the run task , not runRelease task. maybe I try your idea to test it in a free time
